# Trying to control select menu via jquery - simple thing but unable to achieve

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to control select menu items via jquery and want to behave them like tabbing.. but no luck.. any help much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

```
$('#box-wrap .box').eq(0).css({'display':'block'});
$('.select-menu').on('change', function(){                                      
    $('.select-menu option:selected').each(function(){      
            $('#box-wrap .box').fadeOut();
            $('#'+ $(this).data('url')).fadeIn();
            });
        });
```

here is jsfiddle url:

http://jsfiddle.net/mufeedahmad/FLzQc/1/

Comment: Want to behave like tabbing means? When option is selected from 1st select, the box should show option from 1st select and when option is selected from 2nd select, then 2nd select option?

Comment: Do you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/FLzQc/3/

Comment: @RaunakKathuria... somthing around... but only single div will be visible in a time.

Comment: Mufeed: Please check my solution. Hope you get what you want.

Comment: @buthram... yes... whatever option is selected relevant box will appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming that you want like this:**

When option is selected from 1st select, the box should show as option from 1st select's selected option and when option is selected from 2nd select, then 2nd select selected option.

Code Used:

```
$('#box-wrap .box').eq(0).css({'display':'block'});
$('.select-menu').on('change', function(){                                          
    var option_id = $(this).find('option:selected').data('url');        
    $('.box').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('id') === option_id){
          $(this).fadeIn(); 
        } else {
           $(this).fadeOut();  
        }
    });    
});
```

**Fiddle Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/budhram/pUse5

Comment: one more thing.. how do we reset other selected menu?

Comment: Use this $(this).siblings().val($(this).siblings().find('option:first').val());  after $('.box').each(function(){...}); iteration. :)